# CakePHP mysql database naming conventions question

Tags: mysql, cakephp, naming-conventions

First: I have read the naming convention rules from CakePHP cookbook, so dont direct me there :) I might though be understanding something incorrectly and if so please correct me ;)

The problem Im having is that I have tables:

- items
- quests

Then I HAD tables:

- item_has_quest_requirements
- quest_has_item_requirements
- quest_has_item_rewards
- quest_has_item_recommends

Which are just HABTM tables with 2 primary keys connecting these 2 tables. Now, some of them also have their OWN specific columns also which is why I had not put them into the same table. For example, **item_has_quest_requirements** has just the keys, but **quest_has_item_requirements** has also *amount* field as do rewards and recommends aswell.

However, if I follow CakePHP naming conventions, I should NOT use composite primary keys and if I wanted to connect 2 tables together as HABTM tables, I should name the tables in alphabetical order by table names. Which means AFAIK that these tables would ALL become: **items_quests** tables which is impossible.

Would the only way be then to create totally new extra table like:
**quest_requirements** which would have the *amount* column and then make the HABTM table like: **items_quest_requirements** ?

This is what I have been rolling in my mind so could you enlighten a bit what would be the best approach?

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to store additional data in the joining HABTM tables in CakePHP.  Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no naming conventions for when you have *multiple* associations between two tables. In this case you have to specify the involved tables manually in your models, see http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together#hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM-1044 for details.

However, you mention some join tables will contain additional columns. For such a scenario it might be a better approach to use [Join Models](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together#hasMany-through-The-Join-Model-1650) (also known as "hasMany through") instead of HABTM associations.

Comment: +1.  the OP should define a HABTM relationship for the `item_has_quest_requirements` association, and then Join Models for the other three.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reproduce it with http://cakeapp.com, it forces you to use the cake naming conventions. And allows you to download the DB schema afterwards.